# Rails turbolinks XHR get request doesn't load assets?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Rails XHR get request is not instantiating the corresponding `js` file.

Example XHR `localhost/admin` does NOT load `assets/admin.js` which is breaking my `js` functionality. The only way `admin.js` will load is with a hard browser refresh.

If I include all the `js` code within `admin-index` view (that works too), but I want to keep it separated.

I tried updating `development.rb` as:

```
config.assets.debug = false
```

And tried adding this:

```
config.assets.precompile += %w( *.css *.js )
```

Can someone explain to me how to go about this please? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this problem by adding the `jquery-turbolinks` gem. https://github.com/kossnocorp/jquery.turbolinks

Gemfile:

```
gem 'jquery-turbolinks'
```

Add it to your JavaScript manifest file, in this order:

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery.turbolinks
//= require jquery_ujs
//
// ... your other scripts here ...
//
//= require turbolinks
```